# Is there a way I can switch on my computer or NAS with a phone call?

Tags: nas, wake-up, telephony, wake-on-demand

I would like to know if there is a way to switch on a computer or a NAS using a phone call received through a RJ11. I was thinking of sending the number followed by a password e.g. `mytelnumber#password` to wake up the computer from the off state.

I am aware of Wake-on-LAN (WOL) but I would like to understand if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is short and simple: It is unlikely that you will be able to get this to work for the simple reason that the RJ11/RJ15 is very old, and all technology that would utilize this has been replaced with VOIP based solutions.

In theory it is possible, but you would need a system that you can phone to with a controller that can control a switch.

It is far cheaper to utilize existing systems that require an active internet connection instead. You basically send a packet over the internet to a specific port, or login to a website to control the switch remotely. These are still DIY, but costs would approximate 50$ rather than an all-in telephone system of $2000 that your question would require.

Comment: Thanks I though with a voice modem I could get something, and also some extra tool like answering directly from my PC to land phone calls.

Comment: Well, it is possible, but this technology was not really created for the consumer back in the days. The enterprise gear used ISDN, and ISDN uses RJ25 connectors, they have the size of RJ45 but use 6 cables instead of 8 internally. That said a phoneline is an analog system designed to handle low voltage audio signals. Its not suitable for digital stuff so requires lots of conversions and switching for it to work reliably.